# Xcode: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using fgetc() in C

Tags: c, file, exc-bad-access, fgetc

I am trying to load a map for a game from a txt file, but Xcode gives me this error 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' when I try to read from a file using fgetc() function.

I tried to do the same in another IDE and it works perfectly fine, but Xcode keeps giving me this error. I even tried fscanf(), but unsuccessful.

Here is the code:

```
FILE* file = fopen("res/txt/map_level_1.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open the file!\n");
    return;
}

char c = fgetc(file); // error EXC_BAD_ACCESS
printf("%c", c);

fclose(file);
```

Help me to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do not handle the case `file == NULL` properly, you have to bail out (i.e. `return`) on the error, instead the code path leads to the fgetc, giving a segfault.

Comment: `printf("%s", &c);` --> `printf("%c", c);`

Comment: but i still get the error in Xcode, whereas in another IDE it works.

Comment: @KirillSaidov AFAICS this must be out of the scope of what you show here then... You could try to provide more context (ideally a complete and minimal example)

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`, so (At the least) the returned value from `fgetc()` needs to be cast to `char`.   However, unless the compiler warnings are enabled, the compiler will not tell you about that problem.

Comment: When changing code that has been commented upon.  insert an 'EDIT' and the new code, do not change the original code.  Changing the original code results in certain comments being obsolete and leads to confusion

Comment: regarding: `printf("%s", c);`   This is the cause of your 'Error Bad Access' because it is expecting the contents of the variable 'c' to be a pointer to a place in memory to get the characters to print.   As it is, it is undefined behavior because the resulting address can be anywhere in memory including areas that your program does not have (legal) access to.  And if your program just happens to have access to the specific memory address, the location of a NUL byte, to end the '%s' output might be an area that your program does NOT have (legal) access to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your working directory to your file location.

On the menu bar, select `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`, then `Run -> Options`. Under `Working Directory`, enable `Custom Working Directory` and choose your file location.